# Excel VBA Hyperlinks Function Between Sheets not activating cell

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

I am working on an excel workbook with two sheets. In column C of the first sheet (Sheet1!C1:C500) I have a string in each cell. I wrote up the following code to find where that string occurs in column B of sheet 2 (Sheet2!B1:B184) and convert the cell in Sheet 1 to a hyperlink to its corresponding cell in Sheet 2.

```
Sub HypLinks()

    Dim NametoFind As String

    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

    For Each c In Range(Range("C1"),_
    Range("C1").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlUp))
        NametoFind = c.Value
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
        Set gg = Range(Range("B1"),_ 
       Range("B1").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlUp)).Find(NametoFind,_ 
        LookIn:=xlValues)
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range("Sheet1!C" & c.Row),_ 
        Address:="", SubAddress:="#Sheet2!" & gg.Address,_
        TextToDisplay:=c.Value
    Next

End Sub
```

Everything works fine except for the fact that when I click the hyperlink it only takes me to Sheet2 but does not activate the cell specified by gg.Address. If I remove the "#Sheet2!" the cell specified by gg.Address is activated but in Sheet 1 not sheet 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be solved by changing

```
Set gg = Range(Range("B1"), _
Range("B1").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlUp)).Find(NametoFind, _
LookIn:=xlValues)
```

to

```
Set gg = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1"), _
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlUp)).Find(NametoFind, _
LookIn:=xlValues)
```

That is becuase you have not fully qualified your cells.

Having said that, it is a very complicated and unreliable way of doing it. I would recommend, declaring objects, variables and then work with them. Also use error handling. For example if there is no match found then `gg.Address` will give you an error :)

**Edit**

See this example. Here you do not need to even activate the worksheets

```
Sub HypLinks()
    Dim wsA As Worksheet, wsB As Worksheet
    Dim NametoFind As String
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim gg As Range, aCell As Range
    Dim rngA As Range, rngB As Range

    '~~> Set your worksheets
    Set wsA = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsB = Sheets("Sheet2")

    '~~> Sheet2
    With wsB
        '~~> Find last row in Col B
        lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        '~~> Set you range
        Set rngB = .Range("B1:B" & lRow)
    End With

    '~~> Sheet1
    With wsA
        '~~> Find last row in Col C
        lRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        '~~> Set you range
        Set rngA = .Range("C1:C" & lRow)

        '~~> looping through the range
        For Each aCell In rngA
            NametoFind = aCell.Value

            Set gg = rngB.Find(NametoFind, LookIn:=xlValues)

            '~~> If find returns a match
            If Not gg Is Nothing Then
                wsB.Hyperlinks.Add wsA.Range("Sheet1!C" & aCell.row), _
                Address:="", SubAddress:="#Sheet2!" & gg.Address, _
                TextToDisplay:=aCell.Value
            End If
        Next aCell
    End With
End Sub
```